# Display image from database in a php table

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a simple form which someone fills out and then another form which runs a query to retrieve the data.

Been toying around with the idea of including a images upload in the form and then getting the table to display the form data including this image.

this is some of the code i have

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

    //==========================================
    //  CONNECT TO THE LOCAL DATABASE
    //==========================================
    $user_name = "xxxxxx";
    $pass_word = "xxxxxx";
    $database = "xxxxx";
    $server = "xxxxxx";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {



        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE L1 = '$uname' AND L2 = '" .md5 ($_POST['password'])."'";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //====================================================
    //  CHECK TO SEE IF THE $result VARIABLE IS TRUE
    //====================================================

        if ($result) {
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                $color="1";


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entry, students   WHERE entry.studentName = students.studentName AND students.L1='$uname' ") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<p>You records as of ";
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Date</th><th>Student Name</th> <th>Tutor name</th> <th>Procedure name</th> <th>Grade</th><th>Student Reflection</th><th>Tutor Comments</th><th>Professionalism</th> <th>Communication</th> <th>Alert</th> <th>Dispute</th><th>Username</th> <th>Image</th></tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor= >
<td>".$row['date']."</td><td>".$row['studentName']."</td><td>".$row['tutorName']."</td><td>".$row['procedureName']."</td><td>".$row['grade']."</td><td>".$row['studentReflection']."</td><td>".$row['tutorComments']."</td><td>".$row['professionalism']."</td><td>".$row['communication']."</td><td>".$row['alert']."</td><td>".$row['dispute']."<td>".$row['L1']."</td></td>
<td><img src='images/".$row['studentImage']."'></td>;


</tr>";

// Set $color==2, for switching to other color
$color="2";
}

// When $color not equal 1, use this table row color
else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='#4eb557'>
<td>".$row['date']."</td><td>".$row['studentName']."</td><td>".$row['tutorName']."</td><td>".$row['procedureName']."</td><td>".$row['grade']."</td><td>".$row['studentReflection']."</td><td>".$row['tutorComments']."</td><td>".$row['professionalism']."</td><td>".$row['communication']."</td><td>".$row['alert']."</td><td>".$row['dispute']."<td>".$row['L1']."</td></td>
<td><img src='images/".$row['studentImage']."'></td>;
</tr>";
// Set $color back to 1
$color="1";
}

}
echo '</table>';
```

When the results come back I have fetched all the data apart from the image which is just displayed as a load of characters.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should be uploading the image as a file and storing the path to it in your database.

Comment: Are you storing the image data in the database or a path to the actual image?

Comment: I have tried both ways but neither seems to work. So am going to try get it working by storing the image in the database

Comment: Never store images directly in the database. Always store them in a folder and store the path to the image in the database.

Once you have done that, check what is being stored in the 'studentImage' field. Then put that link the browser and see if you see the image.

Let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Does your form has this?

```
enctype=multipart/form-data
```

in it? If not you won't be able to upload the image as a file.
Make sure your form looks atleast like this:

```
<form method="post" action="URL_THINGY" enctype=multipart/form-data>
     (The rest of your form here)
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store image contents in a database and then display with PHP, you should do two things:

1. do a base64 encode, before you store it in database, so the data does not consist of strange/faulty characters
2. when displaying the image, echo them in your php and set file header to image:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

But as some already said, it is better to `generate` a random name for your image, store it in a folder and store **only** the path to the image in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Since you *need* to store images in the db, here's an SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758548/how-to-display-all-the-images-stored-inside-a-database) to someone with the same problem.

Comment: I don't need to store them in the db but just thought it would be the easier option.

Comment: I meant since you are already storing them, that link will show you how to properly retreive them from the db and display them. The better solution is to store them in the file system and just store the path in the db.