# how to display image from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display all the images stored inside a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758548/how-to-display-all-the-images-stored-inside-a-database)

syntax:

table syntax:

```
create table users(id int, idimage blob);
```

how to retrieve image and display?

```
$sql =mysql_query("SELECT idimage FROM users WHERE 1d=3");
//$resultimg = mysql_fetch_row("$sql");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $sql ) ){ $IMDs[] = $row[0]; }
echo "<img src='".$IMDs[0]."'/>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Do the images exist as files, referencable by the plain src= link? If they are in the database, your webserver won't find them. Create a handler script, adapt the image urls.

Comment: Probability of an anonymous user employing `mysql_query` in a question: way too high. I'm curious where you learned this awful habit because I'm suspecting w3schools might have been involved. PDO or `mysqli` are the only way you should be creating new applications because of the [serious hazards](http://bobby-tables.com/php) with the old interface.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a `blob` field.

In MySQL, there's a datatype called `blob`. You can use that to create it.

There's a [**tutorial**](http://vikasmahajan.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/inserting-and-displaying-images-in-mysql-using-php/) on how to do that.

#### Inserting the image into DB:

```
# If no error
if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    # Check if the file is uploaded via HTTP POST
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
        $imgData = file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
        mysqli_connect("localhost", "$username", "$password");
        mysqli_select_db ("$dbname");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `idimage` ) VALUES ('{$imgData}')";
        mysqli_query($sql);
    }
}
```

#### Displaying the image from the DB:

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
           # Connect to DB
           $link = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
           mysqli_select_db("$database") or die(mysqli_error());

           # SQL Statement
           $sql = "SELECT `idimage` FROM `users` WHERE id=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ";";
           $result = mysqli_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());

           # Set header
           header("Content-type: image/png");
           echo mysqli_result($result, 0);
      }
      else
           echo 'Please check the ID!';
 ?>
```

#### It is better to avoid `mysql_*` functions instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Osiris Added the tutorial link. Will put some gist in a few mins... :)

Comment: hi i'm not using insert query to insert data. i used to manually enter the data. so how i can retrieve image and display also

Comment: @user1799052 if you manually insert data then I think you just enter the URL of image, not image itself. You have to change your field type into your database instead of blob.

Comment: @user1799052 See the **second part**. If you are manually entering, how are you doing it?

Comment: syntax: create table users(id int, image blob) i used above syntax, but i'm able to retrieve image. if we use blob variable, it automatic create browse button, we just click browse the image and easy to insert. i used startfield technologies sec. url they give every thing..

Comment: @user1799052 **INSERTING PROCEDURE PLEASE** Not the creation. Everyone knows the the DDL is the same! How are you manually inserting?

Comment: You're using `mysqli` in this example and you're not using placeholders? Terrible. Especially with binary data involved.

Comment: correct binary data attributes

Comment: @tadman Just a **pseudo** code. Please feel free to correct it. And the OP is more interested on retrieving that inserting.

Comment: @user1799052 I don't get you.

Comment: $sq1l =mysql_query("SELECT idimage FROM users WHERE id=3");
$resultimg = mysql_num_rows($sq1l);


while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ($sq1l) )
{
$idimage = $row["idimage"];  
}
echo "<img src = '$idimage' >";

Comment: @user1799052 Can you update this in the question. Unable to get the full sense of it. :|

Comment: Pseudo-code is not code that could actually work. It's literally one more short line to use placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

do you have the full path of the image in the variable $IMDs[0].
if not you have to give the path of your image in src tag

```
<img src="path/to/your/image" />
```

Comment: i could n't find the image path in mysql database

Comment: then which is the path to your image????? give the path+file name on the src tag

Comment: @DeepuSuresh Your answer is totally wrong buddy. The OP is storing the image itself in the DB. Got it? Edit it before someone downvotes you!