# Display all the images using while loop.but its not working

Tags: php, mysql

Display all the images using loop from DB.this is my code. Image is saved to database as bite format. can't retrieve and display all the images using loop. for example img1,img2,img3 etc...Anyone know what i might be doing wrong?

```
$username = "root";
$password = "123";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "test";
@mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database:      ".mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
$content = $row['image'];
echo $content;
}
```

Comment: You can't serve multiple images in this way. Once you send a header, only one image can be outputted. Sending a second header and a second output after that is not possible. See for example [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: Just... what do you imagine the result would look like...?!

Comment: @Boaz thanks for your vital info. then how can i display all the images. i used to store like this method                                              $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);
      
      $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
      $query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
      $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

Comment: @arun do you want to view all the images in one page?

Comment: @deceze:thanks for your reply.i want look like images in list view img1,img2,img3 etc..

Comment: @arun You can create one script to output the HTML markup with `img` tags, and another script to serve a single image like in your example. See for example [How to display all the images stored inside a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758548/how-to-display-all-the-images-stored-inside-a-database)

Comment: Then you need to make an HTML page with `<img>` elements, each of which links to *one* individual image which you can output this way.

Comment: @Adnan yes.i want to display all images like a list view in a page.

Comment: @Boaz actually i store images in file format. how can i fetch the source for <img> tag? if i done this means the output will be showing like a encrypted format.

Comment: @arun You can also try Adnan's answer.

Comment: @deceze i have stored the images in a file format.if i used <img> tag the output will be in encrypted format.its not displaying the images.

Comment: @Boaz yeah i m going to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the images in HTML format by doing something like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" /><br />';
}
```

Since you'll be fetching the images from the database in binary, you can simply [encode them in Base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and send them to the browser

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple method,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$content = $row['image'];
echo "<img src='path/.$content'>";
}
```

Comment: Would mind explaining why you think this would solve the problem?

Comment: why it wouldn't work ?

Comment: Because the OP is storing the images in binary in the database. He doesn't have an actual path containing the images. But for the future, you're the one writing the answer, so you're the one who should prove his/her claim.

Comment: if you are storing images with their full path in DB then you just need to fetch that field other wise you have to give the path or simply define as constant value