# How to print image taken from Wamp Server?

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I have picture stored in Wamp server and would like to display on my PHP

I know this question has been asked alot and was following the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758548/how-to-display-all-the-images-stored-inside-a-database). The only things differ is that my table called `advertisement` contains only a blob-kind of column. How do I use it to display into my PHP?

I would like to ask whether if there is any simpler solution for me to grab the image straight from the database? And I do also wonder where does Wamp Server store the image? Is there any folder where the Wamp Server would store the picture of the database in a particular folder or isn't?

I'm sorry if there are solutions provided and I'm still asking.

Comment: I guess this is an html problem and not php.

Comment: Yea. I'm sorry because I'm don't know how was it. Now my problem is solved. Sorry for wasting your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, assuming `$image` variable is retreived from database
If you have many images foreach loop them.

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>"/>`

But it is best to upload images to server and store links in database, faster and less complicated

Comment: You sir surely a genius in this field. Thanks alot !